# Write multiple array values to csv file in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Consider arrays A,B,C,D with some values. How to copy the values the each array as column in the csv file.

Can anyone help me with the code. I have created arrays like this and assigning values dynamically.

```
import numpy as np

A = []
A.append(values)
A1 = np.array(A)
B = []
B.append(values)
B1 = np.array(B)

np.savetxt(filename, zip(A1, B1), delimiter=',', fmt='%f')
```

It is throwing error:

> Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Comment: Don't post code as images. Edit your question and format the code as a code block. I can't copy the image into my shell and test it.

Comment: The code you show is incomplete. I have no idea what any of the elements contain.

Comment: what is in `values`?

Comment: `savetxt` turns its input into an array first.  What is `np.array(zip...)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.vstack to stack the arrays on top of each other and then use np.savetxt

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]
c = [3,4,5,6]
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = np.array(c)
d = np.vstack((a,b,c))
np.savetxt("file.csv", d, delimiter=",", fmt='% 4d')
```